# Does iOS provide a function to get a device-specific suffix string?

Tags: ios

On iOS there is this nice feature that an app developer can specify device-specific resources or keys in `Info.plist` by tacking on a device-specific suffix to the base name of the resource or key. Currently we have `~ipad` and `~iphone`.

I would like to use the same system for some of my app's registration domain user defaults that should have different values on the various devices. Do you know of a function or method in iOS that I can call to get the current device suffix? Although it is simple to code this myself, I prefer to use the system API whenever that is possible.

I don't really care whether the system gives me `~ipad` and `~iphone`, the strings just need to be unique for each device. I also prefer something that is human readable, which is why I am not enthusiastic about using `UIDevice.userInterfaceIdiom` (that's just a number). I also looked at `UIDevice.model` but I am unsure if this would be suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case there is no positive answer, this is how my implementation of the desired function looks:

```
// NSStringAdditions.h
@interface NSString(NSStringAdditions)
- (NSString*) stringByAppendingDeviceSuffix;
@end


// NSStringAdditions.m
- (NSString*) stringByAppendingDeviceSuffix
{
  static NSString* deviceSuffix = nil;
  if (! deviceSuffix)
  {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
      deviceSuffix = @"~iphone";
    else
      deviceSuffix = @"~ipad";
  }
  return [self stringByAppendingString:deviceSuffix];
}
```

Comment: User interface idiom is the best value to use to distinguish between iPhone and iPad, and although there are other string properties on UIDevice (e.g. model) that give info about the device type in string format, it would be risky to use them for the purpose you desire.  The approach you are using is best imo.